# Sending Data to Target Client with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, client

For example, in the client side, i have two registred and online user.

**UID 1 : Leon** 
**UID 2 : Albert**

**Leon** wants to know how much have credit.

for example, **Leon** hit the button to get credit, so:

```
socket.emit('my_credit', 1);
```

And in the server side, i use this code:

**Example:**

```
var express = require('express');
var server  = express();
var app    = require('http').createServer(server);
var io     = module.exports.io = require('socket.io')(app);

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('my_credit', function(uid){
       getUserCredit(uid, (result) => {
            socket.emit('my_credit', result);
        })
    });

});
```

Now, in the client side, all users receive this value!
If I want only Leon to receive this value, how can i do ?

How can i do in the **server side** to find currect id ?

Comment: Please read again, i edited post 

Answer (score 2):

For sending message to **target client**, use `to` [function](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-to-room):

**Eg:**

```
io.sockets.to(/* Unique ID */).emit('message');
```

**Or:**

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('check', function(){
        io.sockets.to(socket.id).emit('check', 'Just You: ' + socket.id);
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes, Very Thanks. But i need to use front user id instead of socket.id. is there a way ?

Answer (score 1):

Yo!
So basically, at the moment, I dont know any other solutions than checking socket id.
Example to emit client side:

```
socket.emit('my_credit', {user: 1, id: socket.id});
```

Receiving server side :

```
var express = require('express');
var server  = express();
var app    = require('http').createServer(server);
var io     = module.exports.io = require('socket.io')(app);

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('my_credit', function(uid){
        getUserCredit(uid.user, function(result){
            socket.emit('my_credit', {res: result, id: uid.id});
        })
    });

});
```

And receiving client side :

```
socket.on('my_credit', (message) => {
if (message.id !== socket.id) return;
// your code here
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Koro. i don't want to check this in the client side. Is there a way to check this on the server side ?

Comment: Honestly idk, if needed you can always [read the docs](https://socket.io) :)

Comment: i read all, but i cant find answer, 
And i'm surprised why i can't find this important issue in the source.
i need a little function for use in the server side.

Comment: I'm going to check that tmr, I'll keep you updated :)

Comment: keeping you updated, `socket` is only the client socket so to send data to the client you just have to do `socket.emit('my_credit', {res: result});` other ones will not receive it